# Запись в csv файл в разные ячейки

Tags: java, excel, csv

Мне нужно, чтобы данные из массива выводились в csv файл в строчку(чтобы в последующем в excele они были в разных ячейках).

**Вот код:**

Я создала сам csv-файл:

```
String csv = "data.csv";
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv, true));
//Create record
String [] record = name.trim().split(",");
String str_track = sc.nextLine();
writer.writeNext(record);
```

Далее я делю строку на элементы, создав из них массив:

```
String [] str_tr;
String delimeter = "\t"; // Разделитель
str_tr = str_track.split(delimeter);
```

И я не знаю, как правильно вывести их в таблицу, подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Вот как правильно вывести их в таблицу:

```
Row currentRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
for(int i=0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
    if(NumberUtils.isDigits(nextLine[i])) {
        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(nextLine[i]));
    } else if (NumberUtils.isNumber(nextLine[i])) {
        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(nextLine[i]));
    } else {
        currentRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(nextLine[i])
    }
}
```

Следующие депенденсы нужно вставить

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Простите, а какая библиотека используется? @Roman C

Comment: См. обновление.