# Scanner не считывает нужные мне параметры

Tags: java, scanner

Код должен считывать строковые значения координат ячейки матрицы, например, 3 1 при этом пропуская мимо себя коодинаты написанные словами, например, three one или one. После того, как координаты были успешно введены, метод Parse преобразовывает строковые значения в переменные типа int. По итогу, программа пропускает как числа, так и слова. На что нужно обратить внимание?

Вот код:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num1 = null;
    String num2 = null;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+$");
    Matcher m1 = null;
    Matcher m2 = null;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter the coordinates: ");
        num1 = scn.next();
        num2 = scn.nextLine();
        m1 = p.matcher(num1);
        m2 = p.matcher(num2);
        System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
    } while(!m1.matches() && !m2.matches() || (!m1.matches() || !m2.matches())); 

    int coordRow = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    int coordCol = Integer.parseInt(num2);

    System.out.print("Coordinates are: " + coordRow + " " + coordCol);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: Обратить внимание можно на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/839645/204920).